# Role based security mechanism for attributes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'm looking for a plugin that provides a role based authorization mechanism for securing read/write access to attributes.  I'm picturing something along the lines of declarative_authorization for white listing attributes of model objects.  I've spent some time looking around but have come up short, does anyone know of anything?

EDIT:  I'm using declarative_authorization to control which users have access to what actions in the controller, but I need something similar that provides access control to the attributes of each model object.  I'm trying to prevent information leakage through the web API or users from crafting malicious posts.  I can do this through the mass_assignment_authorizer but I was hoping some plugin did this already.

Comment: maybe cancan, dont know if it's support secure read/write

Comment: There is an old list of rails authorization plugin here: http://steffenbartsch.com/blog/2008/08/rails-authorization-plugins/. Note that it does not list cancan, but according to your post, it looks like you want security at the model level, which cancan does not support as far as I know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Protect sensitive attributes w/ declarative_authorization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269333/protect-sensitive-attributes-w-declarative-authorization)

Answer (score 1):

CanCan Branch 2.0

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/tree/2.0

Edit:

The continuation of CanCan is called CanCanCan.

See https://github.com/bryanrite/cancancan

Comment: It looks like it's exactly what I wanted but, the project is mostly dead.

Comment: for better or worse, we are using it in production

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a model / controller pair for each controller, and then allowing each role only to access methods in its controller(s)? Then you can make a before_filter in each controller that makes sure each user has permission to use methods in that controller.

Comment: +1 @charlie - Good idea of getting started for your own permission based controll system.